# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I was trying to revise some of the concepts of Java Web development under the hood and was going through the usage of servlets once again. So, I created a Jakarta EE project from IntelliJ and am using embedded Tomcat with Maven for this project. Here is the pom.xml file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.arka99</groupId>
    <artifactId>Restaurant</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Restaurant</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.86</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Embedded tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In addition, here is the code I have written to use embedded tomcat in my project.

```
package com.arka99.restaurant.main;
import org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot;
import org.apache. Catalina.core.StandardContext;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot;

import java.io.File;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String webAppLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(7070);
        try {
            StandardContext standardContext = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/",
                    new File(webAppLocation).getAbsolutePath());
            File additionalWebInfClasses = new File("target/classes");
            WebResourceRoot resourceRoot = new StandardRoot(standardContext);
            resourceRoot.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resourceRoot, "/WEB-INF/classes",
                    additionalWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
            standardContext.setResources(resourceRoot);

            tomcat.start();
            tomcat.getServer().await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code I have written for HelloWorldServlet.

```
package com.arka99.restaurant.servlets;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;

import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "The current time is: " + new Date();
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.println("<html><body>");
        printWriter.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
        printWriter.println("<p>" + message + "</p>");
        printWriter.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

This is the web.xml file used for this project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
    <display-name>Arka's Restaurant</display-name>
    <description>
        The menu and online ordering system for Arka's restaurant.
    </description>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.arka99.restaurant.servlets.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This project works as per my expectation when I use the javax servlet instead of the Jakarta servlet in the servlet class I have prepared. When I use `jakarta.servlet.http` as default import for servlet, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1021)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:932)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

My query is that if I want to use Jakarta servlet in my projects, what needs to be done? What am I missing here?

Comment: Tomcat 8.x doesn't provide Servlet 5.0. It provides Servlet 3.1. You need a minimum of Tomcat 10.x. See abovelinked duplicate.